# Managing Chrome Extensions via Admin SDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-admin-settings-api

We manage over 10,000 Chromebooks via Google Admin Console and we are having constant issues with Chrome extensions being installed (games, vpns, etc) and used by students. Our OU is broken down per school, student/teacher, grade. We are on track to block ALL extensions and enabling an "allowed" list.

The limitations of Google Admin Console makes this very difficult (on top of being slow) with its clunky interface. I've been researching to possibly programmatically manage the extensions. This way someone can submit a request for an extension, our admin staff can review it, and we can enable it - automatically adding it to the list of allowed extensions.

Is this possible? I searched the admin sdk for hours and can't find a mention of this. I attached a screenshot of how it would be managed manually.

[image: Setting inside Google Admin]